# <bound method PolyCollection.get_paths of <matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection object

Tags: methods, matplotlib

Is there a way to get at all the paths with matplotlib1.3.0?

I am using hexbin and create the following output: "hex31mm", which is a:

```
In [42]: type(hex31mm)
Out[42]: matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection
```

My aim is to use the method "get_paths" as is in "matplotlib 1.1.0" for the function linked below but with the newer version of "matplotlib 3.0.1"
Interestingly: "get_paths" under matplotlib 3.0.1, yields "802" distinct paths as below:

```
In [41]: len(hex31mm.get_paths())
Out[41]: 802
```

Yet "get_paths" under matplotlib 1.3.0, for this same object "hex31mm" yields only one path as below:

```
In[1] len(hex31mm.get_paths())
Out[1]: 1
```

Please check link below for more details, any help much appreciated!

NOTE:

I am sure the information for all paths are part of the object in both cases because the hexbin figure that plots up onto the screen is the same under both matplotlib versions, however I require the hexbin centres, hence my insistance of use on the "get_path" method for the linked function.

Sorry to sound repetitive but the function works fine in matplotlib1.1.0 but not under matplotlib1.3.0 and is supposed to return an array (n,2), and each element of that array is the centre (x,y) of n hexbins:

any hints, would be much appreciated...

Comment: Function: http://www.codeshare.io/CoBD1

Answer (score 0):

I think in the newer versions of matplotlib the method: "get_offsets()" does the trick: "hex31mm.get_offsets()" returns the centres which is the output of the function ...